# PHP Verify hashed password

Tags: php, mysql, prepared-statement

I got a users table in my db where the passwords are encrypted with the PASSWORD function.The thing is i want to create a login system i cant figure out how.I know i can use something like this

```
SELECT `username`,`password`
FROM `users`
WHERE `username` = $user 
AND `password` = PASSWORD($password)
```

but i want to use prepared statements so my code looks like this

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username=? AND 
password=?";
//.....
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bind_param("ss", $u,$p);
```

Any ideas?

Comment: if you really want to use the `mysql's PASSWORD` then try executing this query `select PASSWORD('hello')`;

Comment: Please use ***PHP's [built-in functions](http://jayblanchard.net/proper_password_hashing_with_PHP.html)*** to handle password security. If you're using a PHP version less than 5.5 you can use the `password_hash()` [compatibility pack](https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat).  ***It is not necessary to [escape passwords](http://stackoverflow.com/q/36628418/1011527)*** or use any other cleansing mechanism on them before hashing. Doing so *changes* the password and causes unnecessary additional coding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the PASSWORD function inside your SQL query Like this:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username=? AND 
password=PASSWORD(?)";
//.....
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bind_param("ss", $u,$p);
```